# Find the range of $f(x)=x/(3x^2−3x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find the range of $f(x)=x/(3x^2−3x)$

From my computations, the range I get is all reals except for -1/3. However, after I looking at the graph of the function on google, it looks as if the range is all reals except for 0. I've been working on this for hours but I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: What is the domain of the function? The reals except from $0$ and $1$?

Answer (score 1):

So we have the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{3x^2-3x}=\frac{1}{3x-3}$. Now set this equal to $y$/ That is,
$$\frac{1}{3x-3}=y$$ This will boil down to $$x=\frac{1}{3y}+{1}$$ You can see that this function is defined for all value except $0$. So the range of the function will be $\Bbb{R}-\{0\}$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x\ne 0$ where $f(x)$ isn't defined we get
$$\frac{x}{3x^2-3x}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{x-1}$$
the latest function is defined everywhere but at $x=1$.

Thus, the graph of $f(x)$ is a shifted version of $\frac{1}{x}$ ( just around $x=1$ instead of $x=0$) and also with a hole at $x=0$.
This determine the range.

Comment: You have left out the condition that $x\neq 0$. This restriction removes $-\frac13$ from the range.

Comment: The equality is only  true for $x \ne 0$

Answer (score 0):

When you knock out the $x$ from top and bottom, you essentially have a hyperbola with the x-axis as the horizontal asymptote. Therefore $y=0$ is out of your range. Next, there is a hole in the graph for $x=0$. The hole is located at $(0,-1/3)$ So this y-value also needs to be taken out of the range. So there are two values that are not in the range. Can you set up your range now?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [horizontal asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Horizontal_asymptotes) of your function where $x \to \infty$:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{3x^2-3x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{3(x-1)} = 0
$$

That's how you get that the range is all $x \neq 0$.